# xargs vs backtick

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe, xargs

More silly questions from the Linux n00b. =D

I'm curious about the performance ramifications of using xargs vs. backticks.

For example, what's the different between:

```
find ./ -name foo* | xargs rm
```

and

```
rm `find ./ -name foo*`
```

It seems to me that it would be a better practice to pipe and use xargs as stuff could be processed in sequential order.

Your thoughts?

-M

Comment: note these commands are basically the same thing -- `xargs` runs one `rm` with the piped-in input as arguments.  John T's answer shows how to run one `rm` for each file found.

Comment: they are not 'basically' the same: xargs runs as many 'rm's as it needs to run to handle all given filenames. to quote 'man xargs': "... and executes the command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times ..." . the backtick solution instead expands the output of find on the commandline and then it runs only ONE rm, plus you might get problems with the number of arguments reaching maximum (see chris answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks hurt when dealing with more complex scripting; you need to carefully escape backticks contents. Because of that I often change them into `$(...)`.

`xargs` might call `rm` multiple times in your example if there is lots of files -- POSIX systems can have upper limit on length of command parameters.

`xargs` has other features that backticks doesn't: f.e. `xargs` can take parameters separated by `\0` byte to deal with filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing only with a few pathnames that do not contain whitespace, then they are equivalent.

On some systems, the maximum length of a single command-line (actually, environment plus arguments sent to an *exec*(2)-family call) is limited (see kern.argmax). On a limited system, if `find` produces too much output, the shell would not be able to fit it all into the surrounding command line. To fix this, `xargs` takes the output of `find` and combines the ‘words’ (yes, words, not lines, see below) into groups that fit into a single command-line.

Second, both `xargs` and the shell (via backticks) will split up `find`'s output into arguments for `rm` by tokenizing the output at every run of any combination of space, tab, or newline characters (this is a simplification since they both have their own quoting rules that are close, but not identical). If `find` `-print`s a pathname of “.//foo/bar quux”, `rm` will eventually see two arguments (“.//foo/bar” and “quux”). If a file named `quux` existed in the cwd from which you started, it would be gone when it was all over (and “.//foo/bar quux” would still be there!).

So the most robust method is to use `find`'s `-print0` and `xargs`'s `-0` POSIX-extension. Working together, they can be used to robustly transport any legal pathname from the output of `find` to the command-line of any other command on any system that supports the two extensions.

```
find . -name foo\* | xargs -0 rm
```

The robustness comes from the fact that the NUL byte that both extensions use to terminate pathnames is the only disallowed byte in just about all (Unix-oid) OSes.

Answer (score 1):

If the program supports multiple arguments in that order, the backticks should perform identically. Since not all programs support multiple arguments like that, the problem arises when a command in backticks is executed and returns multiple results. If you know the latter command will work, use it. If you aren't sure, stick with using `xargs` to be safe. `find` also has a useful `-exec` switch which can be used like so:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -i word {} +
```

where the braces are replaced with the current file match from `find`.

Comment: find has also a useful -delete switch .. which makes -exec rm '{}' ';' pretty useless ...